# How to store a PHP variable from a SQL table INT camp

Tags: php, sql

This is my table:

[image: Database Table]

All I want to do is to obtain the '75' int value from the 'expquim' column to later addition that number into another (75+25) and do an UPDATE to that camp (now it is 100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foremost, there are dozens of ways to accomplish what you want to do.  If you're querying the table, iterating over results and doing some conditional checks, the following will work for you.  This is pseudo code... Check out the function names and what parameters they require.  `$db` is your mysqli connection string.   Obviously replace `tablename` with the name of your table.  The query is designed to only select values that are equal to 75.  Modify the query to obtain whatever results you want to update.

This should get you close to where you want to be.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE idus='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['expquim'] == 75){
      $query2 = "UPDATE tablename SET expquim='".$row['expquim']+25."' WHERE idus='".$row['idus']."' LIMIT 1 ";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$query2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alan If you know the record you want to modify, can save yourself the step of querying the data and iterating over it by updating the value directly with a MySQL query.  `update tablename set field = field+10 where Id = 4;`